# Posterior Density in R

Tags: r, bayesian, posterior

I'm new to the site, and to Bayesian statistics and was hoping to get some help.

I'm currently working through some study exercises and am required to compute the mean and variance of the posterior density in R.  The prior density is represented by a normal curve with a mean of 6 and variance of .25, whereas observed mean from a sample (from a normal density) of n = 24 is 7.69 with variance of 2.0.

Most of the readings and study I've done relate to probability estimates - nothing specifically related to the exercises I'm currently trying to work through.

Any assistance or advice or information would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking - are you asking why your 24-sized sample statistics don't match the theoretical values? One check would be to increase the number of samples and see that improves the sample statistics. If with $n=1000$ you still get a dramatic difference between realisations and theoretical, then there's probably something wrong with your code - I suggest posting the code :)

Comment: Study exercises would fall under the `self-study` tag (which you should add and review the [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for). That calculation would normally be done algebraically (it's reasonably simple), but if you're meant to do it through some form of sampling, perhaps you could indicate which form you've been learning about.

Comment: Your prior density is for what parameter(s)?  Perhaps the mean where you know the variance?